# Representing natural numbers as matrices by use of $\otimes$

Tags: matrices, representation-theory, tensor-products

What I am wanting to do is to find a unique matrix representations for Natural numbers. Say I have the number $n$, how can I represent this number as a matrix in which I can do matrix multiplication on other natural number representations, say $m$ to get a matrix resulting in the actual number that would be the product i.e. a matrix representing $m*n$ I have found something akin to what I am wanting to do if I take the tensor product of 2 matrices For example, say I would like to represent the numbers $a*b$ and $c*d$ where $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{N}$ and are prime :
$$ \mbox{} \left[\begin{array} \\ a & 0 \\ 0 & b  \end{array} \right] \otimes \mbox{} \left[\begin{array} \\ c & 0 \\ 0 & d  \end{array} \right] = \mbox{} \left[\begin{array} \\ a*c & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & a*d & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & b*c & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & b*d   \end{array} \right]$$ But as the product should be $a*b*c*d$, I would like to have the matrix representation: 
 $$\mbox{} \left[\begin{array} \\ a & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & b & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & c & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & d   \end{array} \right]$$

So basically I am just looking to represent each natural number uniquely in matrix format in which some operation gives me a new matrix which uniquely represents the product of natural numbers. I am hoping to do this with the tensor product as I would eventually like to represent numbers uniquely in a complex Hilbert space.

Thanks for your insight,

Brian

Comment: What would this representation accomplish? What do you want it for?

Comment: Well it goes a bit deeper and this might sound a bit crack-pot but starting off to develop a foundation showing how numbers are entangled, and what a measurement on the "entanglement" collapses to. Indeed it gets used for something much less insane than the above, but since I need points in a PID/UFD? - so as to uniquely represent objects I am looking in to associating the natural numbers to these points.

Comment: If someone is going to downvote the question, they should at least mention to what posting requirements and or guidelines it doesn't adhere to..

Comment: I agree people really should explain their reason(s) for downvoting on SE.  I guess in this particular thread, the main reason is that both OP's question and comment are too vague on what s/he is doing, especially on the reason why you want a matrix "representation".  I also double quoted representation as this is not the mathematically correct term to use from what I understood from your question, which may be another reason for the downvote.  Though, this problem of misusing the term 'representation theory' on SE is not rare at all...

Comment: While I myself cannot understand why OP want to "turn natural numbers into matrices", the idea of replacing multiplication of natural numbers (or an element of an algebra) by tensor product is actually one of the key ingredient in modern representation theory, or rather categorification.  In the case of of natural number, consider the category of vector spaces, then isomorphism classes of objects can be identified with (decategorify) natural numbers (being the dimension of space), while the operations: direct sum and tensor product, decategorify to addition and multiplication.

Comment: Let $I_n$ be the $n\times n$ identity matrix. Then $I_n\otimes I_m=I_{nm}$. This seems rather meaningless and random. What's the point?

Comment: @Aaron and Sea Turtles, indeed what I am doing may seem meaningless, and it may be and this is the same thing I wonder about most of the concepts in abstract math, a bunch of "abstract nonsense" a meaning that is only defined in relation to another concepts meaning (beginning a proof by induction that all concepts are meaningless unless given meaning). I am trying to build some new operations based on the uniqueness of natural numbers as a Euclidean domain. The characters of the matrices are the trace and are unique and I am trying to represent natural numbers as vectors in a Hilbert space.

Comment: As for the downvoting, I appreciate the comments about my question sounding pointless as it urges me to look in to whether or not I need to go to all this trouble. I however believe that, as I mentioned in the previous comment, meaning is only in context and believe that at worst I am understanding mathematical concepts better as I look for a solution to my problem (representing a vector in a Hilbert space as a matrix in a Integral Domain - whether prime numbers or not, I can find an isomorphism). At best I help develop new concepts and further science.

Comment: What's wrong with considering the ring $R$ of square matrices with the usual addition and $\otimes$ multiplication? I think sea turtles' embedding $\mathbb Z \to R$ by $1\mapsto I_1$ sounds most reasonable.
I think this kind of curiosity is good and should not be deemed useless :)

Comment: Thanks Peter.  The "What would it be like" questions help me understand how mathematical relationships work. I am definitely looking in to sea turtles thoughts.

Comment: I don't get it. What's wrong with assigning to each natural number $n$ the matrix $[n]$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\bf x$ vector contain natural numbers: ${\bf x}(a) = [x_1(a),x_2(a),\cdots]$ which is the multiplicity of respective prime in $a$'s prime factorization according to some enumeration of primes $[p_1,p_2,\cdots]$:

$$a = \prod_{\forall i} {(p_i)}^{x_i(a)}$$

Now you can build the matrix of outer product of standard basis elements with column vectors:$${\bf e_i} = \cases{1, \text{position }i\\0, \text{all other positions}}$$ $${\bf M}(a) = \sum_{\forall i} ({\bf e_i}{\bf e_i}^T)\cdot {(p_i)}^{{x_i}(a)}$$

Now a simple matrix product ${\bf M}(a) {\bf M}(b) = {\bf M}(ab)$ will have the same representation for $ab$ as it has for $a$ and $b$ and you don't have to use Kronecker product. Also note that $$\det({\bf M}({a})) = \prod_{\forall i}({p_i})^{x_i(a)}=a$$

---

An alternative would be to store block diagonal matrix with entries: $\left[\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\x_i&1\end{array}\right]$. This way the matrix multiplication would give addition of the exponents which satisfies $$p^{x_i(a)} p^{x_i(b)} = p^{x_i(a)+x_i(b)}$$
One advantage of this representation is that we can be sure that we will get away with an integer matrix, even when doing division (although we must allow negative integers). This construction you can build with $${\bf M_2}(a) = {\bf I}_n \otimes \left[\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\0&1\end{array}\right] + \left(\sum_{\forall i} {\bf e_i} {\bf e_i}^T x_i(a) \right)\otimes \left[\begin{array}{cc}0&0\\1&0\end{array}\right]$$

So we do finally get an excuse to use the beloved $\otimes$ Kronecker product.

---

Small examples: if we use $p = [2,3,5,\cdots]$ numbers $6$ and $9$ will have representation:

$${\bf M}(6) = \left[\begin{array}{ccc}2&0&0\\0&3&0\\0&0&1\end{array}\right], \hspace{1cm} {\bf M}(9) = \left[\begin{array}{ccc}1&0&0\\0&9&0\\0&0&1\end{array}\right]$$
And we can confirm that:
$${\bf M}(6){\bf M}(9) = \left[\begin{array}{ccc}2&0&0\\0&27&0\\0&0&1\end{array}\right] = {\bf M}(54), \det({\bf M}(54)) = 2\times 27 = 54 = 6\times9$$

And the second type, where we for simplicity draw a grid to show the block structure imposed by the Kronecker product:

$${\bf M_2}(6) = \left[\begin{array}{cc|cc|cc}1&0&0&0&0&0\\\bf 1&1&0&0&0&0\\\hline0&0&1&0&0&0\\0&0&\bf 1&1&0&0\\\hline0&0&0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&0&\bf 0&1\end{array}\right],\hspace{1cm} {\bf M_2}(9) = \left[\begin{array}{cc|cc|cc}1&0&0&0&0&0\\\bf 0&1&0&0&0&0\\\hline0&0&1&0&0&0\\0&0&\bf 2&1&0&0\\\hline0&0&0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&0&\bf 0&1\end{array}\right]$$

The bold numbers marked in the matrix are the exponents $6 = 2^{\bf 1} \cdot 3^{\bf 1} \cdot 5^{\bf 0}, 9 = 2^{\bf 0} \cdot 3^{\bf 2} \cdot 5^{\bf 0}$